# Nesting of CSS Selectors

Tags: html, css

I have a simple HTML page with divs nested within each other. And then I have another HTML page which displays a grid. The grid is styled using a stylesheet. Now I want to embed this grid within the 1st HTML page. So I have created a div inside the 1st page and set the source as the 2nd HTML page (which contains the code for displaying grid). 
Now the problem is, the stylesheet which was developed had the CSS selectors dependent on the structure of the 2nd Page. But now since I have embedded the code in the 1st file, I think the selectors and not getting applied and hence the grid not getting styled. How do I solve this problem ?

Comment: Could you please post some of your code for better understanding?

Comment: sounds like you should be working with PHP to create templates.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe embedding the grid using an [`<iframe>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/HTML/Element/iframe) would be acceptable for you. Then you would not have to change any CSS code.